# determine key size from public key (PEM format)

Tags: ruby, security, size, certificate, public-key

I'm trying to figure out the size of a public key that I received. How can determine the size from the key? I can't find a simple way in the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/X509/Certificate.html).

What I have is the public key itself, which I receive like this:

```
cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(sock.peer_cert)
pkey = cert.public_key
```

The public key is in PEM format. So you have the start and end line, and in the middle the actual key. Now the key itself is base64 encoded. If I decode that string and count the bytes I get a size. This size includes some extras like exponent and modulus (Is there more?). What I need to know to determine the bits of the public key is how many bytes modulus and exponent (and if there is more, then that as well) take up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
key_length_in_bits = pkey.n.num_bytes * 8
```

Quoting [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28algorithm%29):

> [...] n is used as the modulus for both the public and private keys. Its length, usually expressed in bits, is the key length. [...]

Comment: Or just `pkey.n.num_bits`